# Flask SqlAlchemy bulk inserts with unique constraints

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

*Code is not complete but is enough to express the problem.

Let's say we have two models in a one to many relationship (where `Parent` can have many `Child`):

```
class Child(db.Model):
    __table_args__ = unique by child's name and parent id
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    parent = db.relationship(Parent)

class Parent(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
```

So in this world, parents are unique by their names and a child is unique by their name and their parent id. I want to write a method to bulk insert `Child` models and came up with something like this:

```
def bulk_insert(parent_child_list):
    for parent_name, child_name in parent_child_list:
        parent = Parent.query.filter_by(name=parent_name).first()
        if parent:
            child = Child(name=child_name, parent=parent)
        else:
            child = Child(name=child_name, parent=Parent(name=parent_name))
```

However the issue comes up when you attempt to bulk insert `Child` models with same `Parent` names (e.g `bulk_insert([("john", "alex"), ("john", "kris")])`) since the method will try to insert multiple `Parent` models with the same name thus breaking the unique constraint. This happens because the session commit is external of `bulk_insert`.

One way to do this is to insert all unique `Parent` models first and commit, then insert all the unique `Child` models. However, is there a simpler way to make this work in Flask SqlAlchemy without that custom logic? This seems like a session management problem so I'm suspecting I must be missing something in sqlalchemy that may help with this.

Comment: In your code you never actually add your `child` to a session. Please show how you are doing that.

Comment: Also, please provide working models, or in other words a [mcve].